# Uploading to Google Play

Tags: android, eclipse, upload, google-play

I fished an application and I paid to google play but when I upload it I get this message:

> You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned. You will need to run a
>   zip align tool on your APK and upload it again.

I zip aligned it and I again uploaded then no, I got the same msg, I read around again and found something and I did "Android Tools >> Export Signed Application Package" and I got these:

> New keystore D:\blah blah has been created. Certificate fingerprints:
>   MD5 : xx:xx... SHA1: xx:xx..

But I don't know where to put them. I went to upload the apk application again and I get a message:

> Upload failed You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you
>   need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play.
>   Learn more about debuggable APKs. You uploaded an APK that was signed
>   in debug mode. You need to sign your APK in release mode. Learn more
>   about signing.

I went to

```
android:debuggable="false"
```

in Manifest.xml but there is nothing like it I put there!

I honestly don't know what to do, please, does anyone know how to do it from A to Z? I've looked at a lot of things that haven't helped me.

Comment: Which `Tool` you are using to develop the application.

Comment: Right click on the application in eclipse

Comment: Did you use the latest version of `build-tool`. If use latest version means create new .apk with new key store file.

Comment: The latest build tool?  The 1st beta releases of the Eclipse plugin 5 years ago had this.  This is simply an issue of RTFM.

Answer (score 1):

Dude, all this is clearly outlined in the official docs found here: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Thank you, let me try to do it and I'll msg you